# Node global module getting current run directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to create a node module that has the ability to be installed globally using `npm  install -g mymodulename`. I've got everything in the module working fine if I run `node index.js` in the directory of the module, but now I want to make it so that I can publish it to NPM, and it can be installed and run from any directory.

There is some code in my module that looks at certain files in the directory that it is run in. I'm finding that when I do `npm install -g ./` and then go into a different directory for a test, then run `my-module-command`, the relative path that it is reading is from that of where my module got installed (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/my-module`), not the directory that I'm running it in.

How can my module that is installed globally know where it is being run from? To give an example, I am trying to read the `package.json` file in the directory I'm in. And it is reading the `package.json` file of `/usr/local/bin/my-module/package.json`

I've tried:

```
__dirname
process.args[1]
process.cwd()
```

And just calling straight to `require('./package.json')` directly and none of those work.

Edit here's some code that's breaking in `index.js`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var currentDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
fs.exists(`${currentDir}/node_modules`, function(dir) {
  if (!dir) throw 'node_modules does not exist';
  // do stuff
});
```

In my `package.json`:

```
...
"bin": {
  "my-module": "./index.js"
},
...
```

I try to do `npm install -g ./` in the project directory, and then I cd into a different directory called `/Users/me/Projects/different-project`, where another npm project is, and run `my-module`, and I get `node_modules does not exist`. When I log out `currentDir`, I get `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-module` where I'm expecting is to see `/Users/me/Projects/different-project`.

Comment: Yeah, those methods had no right to work the way you wanted, since they find the directory of your current running script, which is that module. Havr you tried: `var path = require('path'); var appDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);`? I think this should return the application's entry point.

Comment: When I log out `appDir` it shows me `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/my-module`, not the directory it's being executed from :/

Comment: `process.cwd()` should work. This is an example of almost exactly what you're trying to do (granted for a different file name): https://github.com/TechnologyAdvice/DevLab/blob/master/src/config.js#L10

Comment: Very helpful question, and answer from @Fluidbyte - I upvoted another of your answers to say thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `./` at the start of your file path? That should give you the current working directory (or calling `process.cwd()` would work too).

In your case, your code would look like:

```
fs.exists(`./node_modules`, function(dir) {
  if (!dir) throw 'node_modules does not exist';
  // do stuff
});
```

I can see some comments already mention this. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question? I just had a case where I needed a global module to get the directory I'm running the script from and what I suggested above worked like a charm.